# Video Frames are received out of order from ffmpeg H264 native decoder

Tags: ffmpeg

I am facing this issue where in media files containing B frames, I am getting frames out of order, for first frame, I am always getting 'no picture', for rest in some cases, I am getting some random frames from previous decode requests.
Can anyone suggest, what can be the issue here?